# Haskell type unfold then fold to another type

Tags: haskell

I have this parser definition:

```
newtype Parser a = P { getParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }
```

I also have this function:

```
functionMatching :: Parser (Char, String, Char)
functionMatching = (,,) <$> spot (`elem` "\\") <*> getWord <*> spot (`elem` ".")
```

How can I make the below function returning the middle element from (Char, String Char)

```
functionCons:: Parser (Char, String, Char) -> (String, String)
functionCons = undefined
```

Example:

```
getParser functionMatching "\\x.y"
Just (('\\',"x",'.'),"y")
```

I want to extract x and y.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be something like:

```
functionCons (P p) = P $ fmap (\((_,x,_), s) -> (x,s)) . p
```

But I suggest that you declare `Parser a` a functor:

```
newtype Parser a = P { getParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) } 
                   deriving (Functor)

functionCons :: Parser (a,b,c) -> Parser b
functionCons = fmap (\(_,x,_) -> x)
```

This of course isn't quite `Parser (a,b,c) -> (b, String)`, but you need to see if you really need to `unJust` the result. For example:

```
functionCons :: Parser (a,b,c) -> String -> (b,String)
functionCons = unJust . fmap (\(_,x,_) -> x) where
  unJust (P p) s = case p s of
    Just x -> x
    -- if Nothing happens, it will throw a unmatched pattern
```

---

As has been correctly noted in the comments, the type is not the same as requested. It is not possible to get the exact signature `Parser (a,b,c) -> (b, String)` without `functionCons` providing the `String` to be parsed.

Comment: I already have a fmap instance for Parser instance Functor Parser where
    fmap f (P p) = P $ \s -> fmap (applyToFirst f) $ p s

Comment: @CosminMihai good. Then functionCons is even simpler; see update

Comment: Adding a type signature to `functionCons` would help, especially since it does not look to have the requested type in the question.

Comment: @chi thanks, I added clarification that the exact signature cannot be obtained, unless `functionCons` "knows" a string that can be parsed.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:

### Applicatives

I think you are not using applicatives to the extent haskell allows. `functionMatching` returns the delimiting characters, only to have them discarded later. To discard Parser matches, use `*>` and `<*`:

```
functionMatching''' :: Parser String
functionMatching''' = spot (`elem` "\\") *> getWord <* spot (`elem` ".")

functionCons''' :: String -> (String, String)
functionCons''' = fromJust . getParser functionMatching'''
```

How `<*>`, `*>` and `<*` work is easily memorized, they only return what `>` and `<` point to:

- `f <*> x: f x`
- `x  *> y:   y`
- `x <*  y: x`

### Parsers

There is a way more idiomatic way to use parsers. Don't extract the unparsed `String` of `Maybe (a,String)`, *parse* it instead! That is one more call to `getWord`.

```
functionMatching' :: Parser (String, String)
functionMatching' = (,) <$> (spot (=='\\') *> getWord <* spot (=='.')) <*> getWord

functionCons' :: String -> (String, String)
functionCons' = fromJust . evalParser functionMatching'

-- evalParser discards the unparsed String
evalParser :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe a
evalParser p s = fst <$> getParser p s
```

`evalParser` is a useful function analogous to [runState, evalState, execState](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html) you will want to export.

The idea of parsers is to not leave the parser prematurely. The code above will encounter an error (`fromJust` does this) if there is no match. haskell uses `Maybe`s for that, and a `Maybe` already is built into the parser. I do not know what you want to do with that `(String,String)`, but you probably want to pass it to a function `f :: String -> String -> b`. Then a

```
functionMatching'' :: Parser b
functionMatching'' = f <$> (spot (=='\\') *> getWord <* spot (=='.')) <*> getWord
```

will handle mismatches better.